# remove cart total from nav storefront

Tags: storefront

I am attempting to remove the cart total from my main navigation on the storefront.

When I add this bit of code to my child theme css

```
.site-header-cart .cart-contents .amount {
display:none;
}
```

it makes the cart contents display in a line instead of the box that it was in before.  If I remove .cart-contents from the code line it does not change anything.

The reason I need to remove the cart total is because I am using a plugin that allows for custom product customization that vary by price.  The price does not change on the cart total until you click it and I think that will be confusing for customers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We cannot speculate how the html is being affected by css without actually seeing the html...

Comment: You must add your html and css that may affect the issue. It would be better if you could reproduce the issue on JSPlunker

Comment: Where is the HTML located within the themes files?  I have looked in header.php and content-homepage.php

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to just remove the total from the heading and this is what I did so far:

```
#site-header-cart a.cart-contents .woocommerce-Price-amount{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this for my site.

```
.site-header-cart .cart-contents {display:none;}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context on how that applies and explain your answer?